# Taking a value and passing it through a list of structures and returning a list that has the corresponding value

Tags: list, struct, lambda, racket, matching

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a year and a list of structs (defined as incident) as input and spits out the corresponding struct.

```
(define-struct incident (name day mon yr)#:transparent)

(define cake (make-incident "cake" 15 "Apr" 2015))
(define Graduation (make-incident "graduation" 2 "Mar" 2017))

    (define (incidentYr yr aList)
  (foldl
   (lambda (x y) (if (equal? (incident-yr x) yr) (append x y) y))
   '()  aList))

(check-expect (incidentYr 2015 (list (incident "cake" 29 "Apr" 2015) (incident "graduation" 7 "Mar" 2017))) (list (incident "cake" 29 "Apr" 2015)))
```

but the error I get is:

```
    check-expect encountered the following error instead of the expected value, (list (incident "cake" 29 "Apr" 2015)). 
   :: append: expects a list, given (incident "cake" 29 "Apr" 2015)
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the lambda in the foldl, change `(append x y)` to `(append (list x) y)`. You can also change it to `(cons x y)`

A more natural solution would be to use filter instead of fold:

```
(filter (λ (x) (= (incident-yr x) yr)) aList)
```